# How can I derive $~\text{opposite}\cdot\sin^{}\left(\theta_{}\right)+\text{adjacent}\cdot\cos^{}\left(\theta_{}\right)=\tan^{}\left(\theta_{}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Given the below equation .

$$  b \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right) = a \cdot \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  $$

I have to derive the below equation .

$$  b \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} \right) + a \cdot \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right) = \sqrt{ a ^2 + b^2 }  $$

My tries are as below .

$$  \frac{  b   }{  a  } = \frac{  \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)   }{  \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)   }  $$

$$  \frac{  b   }{  a  } = \tan^{}\left( \theta_{}  \right)   $$

$$  \text{adjacent}= a   $$

$$  \text{opposite}= b   $$

$$  \text{hypotenuse}=\sqrt{ a^2+ b ^2 }   $$

$$  b \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} \right) + a \cdot \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)  $$

$$ = b \left( \frac{  b \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)   }{  a  }  \right) +a \left( \frac{  a \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)   }{  b   }  \right)  $$

$$ = \frac{  b^2\cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)   }{  a  } + \frac{  a ^2 \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)   }{  b   }  $$

I've been got stucked from here .

Comment: I think I will replace symbols with more simpler ones .

Comment: I solved it in my own lol .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the last line .

$$  \frac{  b^2\cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)   }{  a  } + \frac{  a ^2 \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)   }{  b   }  $$

Just plug the below ones to the above formula and you can get the RHS of the problem .

$$  \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} \right) = \frac{  b  }{ \sqrt{ a^2+b^2 }    }  $$

$$  \cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right) = \frac{  a  }{ \sqrt{ a^2+b^2 }    }  $$

Comment: You could also plug that directly into $b \sin \theta + a \cos \theta$ to get the result without doing all the extra steps

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The diagram makes it easier. It is consistent with your given conditions with $\frac ba = \tan \theta$. Note that $c = \sqrt{a^2 +b^2}$ (Pythagoras).

From the diagram, $\sin \theta = \frac bc, \cos \theta = \frac ac$.

So $b\sin \theta + a\cos \theta = \frac {b^2}c + \frac {a^2} c = \frac {c^2}c = c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ (QED)